# Finding subsequence pairs

Tags: prolog

The intention of the functions below is to find matching pairs of length 2 subsequences.  E.g. [1,2,3,4,2,3,5] has a matching pair of [2,3].  If I feed a sequence w/out a matching pair the first function gets a memory overflow but the second finishes quickly.

Why the difference and is there a general technique for how to dig into this sort of issue?

```
repeat_pair(Items) :-
    append(_,[X,Y|_],Left),
    append(Left,[X,Y|_],Items).

repeat_pair(Items) :-
    append(Left,[X,Y|_],Items),
    append(_,[X,Y|_],Left).
```

Comment: Upon further reflection I believe it's because in the first variation the first "_" can be instantiated with longer and long test lists without ever making progress.  In the second case we limit the size of Left so that we don't check infinite options.  Just not sure how to avoid this problem in general.

Comment: You rather mean [substrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) than [subsequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence).

Answer (score 2):

As you observe in your comment, in the first variant there is no relation between `Items` and the goal `append(_, [X,Y|_], Left)`, so on backtracking this goal will enumerate all its infinitely many solutions.

Your second approach is the best one for this problem, but indeed in general you sometimes need to restrict the search space in other ways.

The problem with the first clause is that `Left` is completely unconstrained. But we know that we never want it to be longer than `Items`. So we can write a predicate to express "`Items` is a list, and `Left` is a shorter or equal length list":

```
list_shorterorequal(_List, []).
list_shorterorequal([_|List], [_|ShorterOrEqual]) :-
    list_shorterorequal(List, ShorterOrEqual).

?- list_shorterorequal([a, b, c], ShorterOrEqual).
ShorterOrEqual = [] ;
ShorterOrEqual = [_G938] ;
ShorterOrEqual = [_G938, _G941] ;
ShorterOrEqual = [_G938, _G941, _G944].
```

And then you can adapt your first implementation like this:

```
repeat_pair_1x(Items) :-
    list_shorterorequal(Items, Left),
    append(_,[X,Y|_],Left),
    append(Left,[X,Y|_],Items).
```

And this succeeds once, then terminates quickly:

```
?- repeat_pair_1x([1,2,3,4,2,3,5]).
true ;
false.
```

If your Prolog has a `between/3` predicate (they usually do), you could also use that to restrict the length of `Left` *before* we know anything else about `Left` itself:

```
repeat_pair_2x(Items) :-
    length(Items, ItemsLength),
    between(2, ItemsLength, LeftLength),
    length(Left, LeftLength),
    append(_,[X,Y|_],Left),
    append(Left,[X,Y|_],Items).
```

This also terminates nicely:

```
?- repeat_pair_2x([1,2,3,4,2,3,5]).
true ;
false.
```

Note that these two predicates behave slightly differently on the most general query, and in general if the argument of the call is not bound to a finite list:

```
?- repeat_pair_1x(Items).
Items = [_G918, _G924, _G918, _G924|_G940] ;
Items = [_G918, _G924, _G930, _G918, _G924|_G946] ;
Items = [_G918, _G924, _G930, _G924, _G930|_G949] ;
Items = [_G918, _G924, _G930, _G936, _G918, _G924|_G952] ;
Items = [_G918, _G924, _G930, _G936, _G924, _G930|_G955] .

?- repeat_pair_2x(Items).
Items = [_G918, _G921, _G918, _G921] ;
Items = [_G918, _G921, _G918, _G921, _G930] ;
Items = [_G918, _G921, _G924, _G918, _G921] ;
Items = [_G918, _G921, _G924, _G921, _G924] ;
Items = [_G918, _G921, _G918, _G921, _G930, _G933] .
```

By calling `length/2` on `Items` in the second variant, we force it to be a finite list. There might be cases where you don't want this.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog operational semantic is based on chronologic backtracking, and this means that goals order is important for correctness, as it provides instantiation of variables in a predictable way. That said, you could use append/2 instead of append/3 to achieve the same result:

```erlang
repeat_pair(Items) :- append([_,[X,Y],_,[X,Y],_],Items).
```

effectively moving into a library predicate the logic.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the difference ... ?

It suffices to consider the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) of your first  version:

```
repeat_pair(Items) :-
    append(_,[X,Y|_],Left), false,
    append(Left,[X,Y|_],Items).
```

This fragment shares some properties with the original program: In particular, if this fragment loops, then your original program will loop, too.  Now, what might influence termination? Only the variable `Items` might influence it, but all occurrences are behind the **`false`**. So there is no way how `Items` influences termination and the goal `append(_,[X,Y|_],Left)` does not terminate. Thus, even if this program succeeds, it will not terminate. Think of `repeat_pair("abab").`

> ... and is there a general technique for how to dig into this sort of issue?

Yes, there is. Question answered.

(It's above technique called [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice). See the tag for more examples.)

Finally, here is a version using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)s:

```
repeat_pair(Cs) :-
   phrase(( ..., [A,B], ..., [A,B], ... ), Cs).

... --> [] | [_], ...
```

A generalization which also accepts non-lists like `[a,b,a,b|non_list]` is below. Often, such generalizations are preferred, as they are slightly shorter and slightly more efficient and may possess slightly better termination properties (not in this case).

```
repeat_pair(Cs) :-
   phrase(( ..., [A,B], ..., [A,B] ), Cs, _).
```